# Potentially dangerous Request.Form value - Exception

Tags: asp.net, exception, request, dangerous-request

today I receive multiple (50->*) e-mails regarding:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$Content$InputStreet="OzgYPY  <a href="http://effe...").
```

and

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$Content$InputStreet="GVdtWm  <a href="http://mxif...").
```

and

...

on one of my websites. In Global I have some code which sends e-mail when exceptions occur.

The IP address the requests come from is not the same. Is my site under some kind of attack?

Best regards,
Lasse Espeholt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of attacks are common, we're monitoring several hundred sites for clients and are building a database of these attacks currently.

The fact that ASP.NET protects against these is good. you're 'secure by default'.

Cheers,

Phil.

Comment: Okay thanks :) I do need to make a captcha on one of the pages, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think we'd need more detail to be sure but from the message in the email it looks as if someone is entering a value in your Street field that .NET is regarding as dangerous. This could be a number of things, I see from your profile you are form Denmark, are the Street names there likely to contain anything dangerous?

Examples are < and >.

It could just be a really eager user who wants to sign-up? Or a bunch of people from the same area?

What's the context of the site?

Comment: It is request by multiple IP adresses in the same minute. The requests writes something like "saff <a href=''>". No they should not. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: Fair point :) it does sound strange but your code seems to be handling it - is there anyway you could capture all the information they've entered in your email? Maybe this would make it easier to see if it was malicious.

Comment: I don't know actually :/ My "tagwall" does not handle it so I must implement a captcha.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a script injection attack, something/some one is trying to update your form InputStreet input field with script.
More info about [script injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)

Further info: [Script injection attacks and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355989.aspx)

Comment: Okay thanks, but the requests is from different IP addresses?